# Append to a div with a recurring class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of JS that appends the following to a web form on the click of a button. When the div `.remove` is clicked the closest `new-attribute` div is removed. It works fine.

```
<div class="new-attribute">
    <h3>New Attribute</h3>

    <label for="attributeName3">Name:</label>
    <input class"attribute"="" type="text" name="attributeName3">

    <label for="attributeType3">Type:</label>
    <select id="t" class="attribute" name="attributeType3">
        <option value="text" selected="">Text</option>
        <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
        <option value="select-list">Select Option List</option>
        <option value="notes">Notes</option>
    </select>

    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="remove">Delete</div>
</div>
```

In the div "option" I have code to add another form field on the selection of "select-list" in the select input. It does not work. I do not know why. No variable names are clashing. I'm away I shouldnt give the select an id because it is recurrent, I just want to get it working before I make it compliant.

Heres the Js that I'm having trouble with:

```
//select temp
var select="<div class=\"new-option\">"
    + "<h3>new option</h3>"
    + "<label for=\"attributeName"+count+"\">New otion:</label>"
    + "<input class\"attribute\" type=\"text\" name=\"attributeName"+count+"\">"
    + "</div>";

//get value of select
$('#t').change(function() {
    var selectVal = $('#t :selected').val();
    if (selectVal == "select-list") {
        $(this).closest('.option').append(select);
    }   
});
```

The code works with `$(select).appendTo('.option');`
However it appends the code to every instance of the "option" class on the page. I only want it to append to the current or closest one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: not directly related to this question, but you seem to be missing a `=` here `<input class\"attribute\"` (`select` value assignment)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because `closest()` looks up the DOM for the nearest parent element matching the selector, but `.option` is a sibling of `#t`. Try using `next()` instead:

```
$('#t').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "select-list") {
        $(this).next('.option').append(select);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Sir you can use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/7WC4G/1/

```
$('#bob').change(function(){
    $('#nuform').append('<p>your new form here</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using next, prev as it could fail if you change the order.
Instead try using siblings instead of closest in your code:

```
$(this).siblings('.option').append(select);
```

Read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/