# Jquery change() only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Heres my code:

```
//select temp
        var select="<div class=\"new-option\">"
                 + "<h3>new option</h3>"
                 + "<label for=\"attributeName"+count+"\">New otion:</label>"
                 + "<input class=\"attribute\" type=\"text\" name=\"attributeName"+count+"\">"
                 + "</div>";
        //get value of select
        $('.tattribute').change(function() {


            if (this.value == "select-list") {

                $(this).next('.option').append(select);

            }   

            if(this.value!="select-list") {

                $(this).next('.option').remove();

            }

        });
```

The code is appended when select-list is selected from the form. It also removes the code when select-list is not selected. However when I select select-list and then another option it will no longer work. The code is removed but will be append again when I select select-list a second or third time. It only works onces

Heres the html

```
<select id="t" class="attribute" name="attributeType3">
    <option value="text" selected="">Text</option>
    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="select-list">Select Option List</option>
    <option value="notes">Notes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think your problem could be because you are removing the element itself `$(this).next('.option').remove();`.

Comment: @up true and what about .option class? did you mean ('option')

Comment: Where are `.tattribute` and `.option` in your HTML?

Comment: No, the author ;) sorry for missing interpunction

Comment: @AdamWolski: Thats fine mate. Remembering from the previous question posted by the same user, there is a `div` with `class="option"` in his code, so he could be referring to that element. [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548824/append-to-a-div-with-a-recurring-class) is the one, I referred to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hW8sv/ .... The code described in this post isnt working on fiddle for some reason... It works on my computer